# Why is the Tate map lax monoidal (just for abelian groups?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, equivariant-maps

Let $A$ be an abelian group with $G$ action, then  I call the tate map
$$(-)^{tG}: Ab^G \rightarrow Ab$$
$$ A \mapsto \operatorname{coker}(Nm:A_G \rightarrow A^G)$$

where $Nm:x \mapsto \sum_g gx$, is the norm map.

I heard that this map is **lax monoidal** - but I don't see how. In fact I don't even see how there is a well defined map 
$$ A^{tG} \times B^{tG} \rightarrow (A \otimes_{\Bbb Z} B)^{tG}$$

Comment: Perhaps section I.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01799.pdf), in particular footnote 19 on page 43, might be useful.